# c++ display a variable in textbox/label c++

Tags: c++, io, textbox, clr

I'm relatively new in programing with c++ and I'm facing a problem since 2 or 3 days now. I writing a code in Visual basic 2013 C++/CLR with for goal to get datas from sensor through USB and a serial COM. The data acquisition part work and I proved it by displaying the datas in the console. Now to make it more user friendly I have "designed" a UI with textbox,... to display the values. I created the class to link the MyForm.h and MyForm.cpp which work if I put a constant. Now I'm facing a problem which is how to link the variable in the class where I'm getting the data of the sensors to the variable in the class where I write the value in the textbox. Here is the architecture of the code:

MyForm.cpp

```
 #include...

 using namespace...

 //few 
 void name...(){
 }

 //then 
 void output(){
 ...
       while(...){
                ...
                if(...){
                   ...
                   float yaw,... ;
                   ...
                   yaw = RadToDegree(yaw); // value I want to display in the textBox
                   ...
             }
           }          
        }

// then the link to the text box

void Project1::MyForm::yawAngle() {
   this->textBox1->Text = Convert::ToString(yaw);
}
```

MyForm.h

```
//code generated automatically by the UI designer
//then for the textBox

private: void yawAngle();

Private: System::Void MyForm_Load(System::Object^ sender, System::EvenArgs^ e) {
yawAngle();
}
```

The problem is I don't arrive to link the two "yaw" variables. I first tried to integrate the link to the textbox directly in the if loop like a cout which doesn't work for managed/unmanaged problem. I tried to create a global variable  but he didn't worked as well the result was 0 and not updating in the UI; tried the friend function and class and the same. I'm sure its a simple mistake but the fact I don't have to much experience and I'm stack in it doesn't help. Any idea?

Thank you very much.